# Scrapy and frames

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, frames

I need to scrape data from HTML documents, where the data is sometimes directly inside a table, and sometimes inside a table that is inside a `<frameset>` frame. I don't know which until I have received the HTTP response.

Currently I have

```
# works only when data directly in the HTML
rules = [
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'/data/(\w+)-content.htm']), callback='parse_content')
]

# works when data inside a frame
rules = [
    ???
]
```

How do I tell [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) to use the frame **where frameset is present**, and **use the HTML directly** where it isn't?

I am confused about how scrapy handles extracting information from frames. Is there an XPath trick? Do I have to muck around with `Response` objects somehow?

Answer (score 4):

You will have to get the frame source url ( given in the frame src attribute) and use that url as the Request url to get the data in the frames.

Answer (score 1):

Use this rule if you just want to grab frame src urls as well:

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow = (all_subdomains,), tags=('a', 'area', 'frame'), attrs=('href','src')))
```